# How to request properly an authorization code in OAuth2.0?

Tags: spring, callback, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have a glass fish server which runs on port `5000`. It hosts only `.js` and `.html/css` files. I also have a spring server which runs on port `8080`.

If I type 
`http://localhost:5000/app/index.html` in my browser , I get my homepage but other requests are made with port `8080`.   Like `http://localhost:8080/getTodaysWheather` .

It's not my web app , but I'm supposed to work with/test it. I'm adding Oauth2 (Authorize code grant type) support. So my question is :
What port + link for my callback URL must I use ?

What I tried :I set a callback url like `http://localhost:5000/app/index.html` so after the user authorized my app he's redirected to `http://localhost:5000/app/index.html?code=1234` and now I make again a request to my server with port `8080` and give it the fresh code received so that it can use it further to get me an access token.

Is this the way you would also do it ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the OAuth2? Do you want to authenticate a user of the browser-side application running at port 5000 or to delegate rights of that user to the backend Spring application? Why did you decide for the authorization code grant flow?

Comment: @JánHalaša Hi Jan, my Spring app should be able to make some requests on my user's behalf like : getUserGithubRepos or getUserGithubStatistics or getUserGithubComments . So I thought to use the authorization code grant flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Spring application is the user of the OAuth2 access token, then the redirect URL should be pointing to it (port 8080).  I would also keep the authentication URL in the Spring application. So the workflow would be:

1. The frontend (JavaScript app) navigates the browser to a backend URL for authentication e.g. `http://localhost:8080/redirectToOAuth2` (full browser request, not XHR) that will respond with a redirect to your OAuth2 server.
2. After authentication, OAuth2 server redirects the browser to a `redirect URL` of the backend along with the authorization code, such as `http://localhost:8080/authenticated?code=1234`.
3. The backend reads the code, gets access and refresh tokens and responds with a redirect to the frontend application `http://localhost:5000/app/index.html`.

Comment: what do you mean by full browser request ?

Comment: Yes, full browser requests. OAuth2 concept requires it. And it's good for a user to see real URLs - to know he's at a secure authentication service and not a phishing site.

Comment: Sorry, I read the question too quickly. By a full browser request I mean a basic browser navigation - when the whole page changes, not just part of it (using XHR).